# Как обраться к class или id через js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, классы, tag

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой инпут, как можно обратиться  к классу или ид :?

```
<input type="text" name="shipping_address.custom_field.address.1" id="shipping_address_custom_field.address.1" value="" class="form-control   not-required  custom_field.address.1" autocomplete="on">
```

нужно этот v код присвоить этому ^ инпуту

```
$(".custom_field").keypress(function(event){
event = event || window.event;
if (event.charCode && event.charCode!=0 && event.charCode!=46 && (event.charCode < 48 || event.charCode > 57) )
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log($("[id='shipping_address_custom_field.address.1']").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="shipping_address.custom_field.address.1" id="shipping_address_custom_field.address.1" value="AAA" class="form-control   not-required  custom_field.address.1" autocomplete="on">
```